# jQuery Taggd plugin (Edit mode) get back value in input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Im using the jQuery taggd plugin, so far so good. 
I modified a small bit, im using it in edit mode. So when a user types in a value in the textbox it checks if it is a URL or or string, if its a URL it runs a ajax call to a php file which scrapes some data from the url. Url title, description and image. I have created 3 hidden input fields which get populated once the ajax call is finished. Once you click on the SAVE icon it saves the data to the DOM. But i want it to display again once a user clicks on the tag again. At the moment its only displaying the value of the standard input field.

This is the taggd plugin with some small modifications:

```js
/*!
 * jQuery Taggd
 * A helpful plugin that helps you adding 'tags' on images.
 *
 * License: MIT
 */

(function($) {
 'use strict';
 
 var defaults = {
  edit: false,
  
  align: {
   x: 'center',
   y: 'center'
  },

  handlers: {},

  offset: {
   left: 0,
   top: 0
  },
  
  strings: {
   save: '&#x2713;',
   delete: '&#x00D7;'
  }
 };
 
 var methods = {
  show: function() {
   var $this = $(this),
    $label = $this.next();
   
   $this.addClass('active');
   $label.addClass('show').find('input').focus();
  },
  
  hide: function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   
   $this.removeClass('active');
   $this.next().removeClass('show');
  },
  
  toggle: function() {
   var $hover = $(this).next();
   
   if($hover.hasClass('show')) {
    methods.hide.call(this);
   } else {
    methods.show.call(this);
   }
  }
        
 };
 
 
 /****************************************************************
  * TAGGD
  ****************************************************************/
 
 var Taggd = function(element, options, data) {
  var _this = this;
  
  if(options.edit) {
   options.handlers = {
    click: function() {
                    
     _this.hide();
     methods.show.call(this);
    }
   };
  }
  
  this.element = $(element);
  this.options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
  this.data = data;
  this.initialized = false;
  
  if(!this.element.height() || !this.element.width()) {
   this.element.on('load', _this.initialize.bind(this));
  } else this.initialize();
 };
 
 
 /****************************************************************
  * INITIALISATION
  ****************************************************************/
 
 Taggd.prototype.initialize = function() {
  var _this = this;
  
  this.initialized = true;
  
  this.initWrapper();
  this.addDOM();
  
  if(this.options.edit) {
   this.element.on('click', function(e) {
                
    var poffset = $(this).parent().offset(),
     x = (e.pageX - poffset.left) / _this.element.width(),
     y = (e.pageY - poffset.top) / _this.element.height();

    _this.addData({
     x: x,
     y: y,
     text: '',
                    url: '',
                    url_title: '',
                    url_description: '',
                    url_image: ''
    });

    _this.show(_this.data.length - 1);
   });
  }
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
   _this.updateDOM();
  });
 };
 
 Taggd.prototype.initWrapper = function() {
  var wrapper = $('<div class="taggd-wrapper" />');
  this.element.wrap(wrapper);
  
  this.wrapper = this.element.parent('.taggd-wrapper');
 };
 
 Taggd.prototype.alterDOM = function() {
  var _this = this;
  
  this.wrapper.find('.taggd-item-hover').each(function() {
   var $e = $(this),
    
    $input = $('<input id="url" type="text" size="16" />')
     .val($e.text()),
                $url_title = $('<input type="text" id="url_title" class="url_title" />'),
    $button_ok = $('<button />')
     .html(_this.options.strings.save),
                
                $url_description = $('<input type="text" class="url_description" id="url_description" />'),
                $url_image = $('<input type="text" class="url_img" id="url_img" />'),
                $url_preview = $('<div id="content"></div>'),
    $button_delete = $('<button />')
     .html(_this.options.strings.delete);
   
            
   $button_delete.on('click', function() {
    var x = $e.attr('data-x'),
     y = $e.attr('data-y');
    
    _this.data = $.grep(_this.data, function(v) {
     return v.x != x || v.y != y;
    });
    
    _this.addDOM();
    _this.element.triggerHandler('change');
   });
            
            // Typing URL timer
            var typingTimer;
            var doneTypingInterval = 2000;
            
            $input.keyup(function() {
                clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
            });
            
            $input.keydown(function() {
                clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                $url_preview.empty();
            });
            
            // Process URL scrape request
            function doneTyping() {
                var getUrl = $input.val();
                
                if(isURL(getUrl)) {
                    console.log('Typed text is a URL');
                    $url_preview.append('<img src="images/loader.gif" style="width:24px; padding-top:10px; height:24px; margin:0 auto;">');
                    

                    // Get url data by ajax
                    $.post('ajax/Crawl.php', {
                        'url' : getUrl
                    },function(data) {
                        
                        $url_preview.empty();
                        
                        
                        var content = '<h3 class="url_title">' + data.title + '</h3><p class="url_description" style="font-size:11px;">' + data.description + '</p><img class="url_image" src="' + data.images + '" style="width:100%; height:auto;">';
                        $url_preview.append(content);
                        
                        $url_title.val(data.title);
                        $url_description.val(data.description);
                        $url_image.val(data.images);
                        console.log(content);

                        
                    }, 'json');

                } else {
                    console.log('Typed text is a string');
                }
            };

            
            function isURL(url) {
                
                var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
                '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
                '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
                '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
                '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
                '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
                
                if(!pattern.test(url)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if(!/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test(url)) {

                        url = 'http://'+url;
                        $input.val(url); 
                }
                return true;
                }
   
             };

                       
            $button_ok.on('click', function() {
    var x = $e.attr('data-x'),
     y = $e.attr('data-y'),
                    
     item = $.grep(_this.data, function(v) {
      return v.x == x && v.y == y;
     }).pop();
    
    if(item) item.text = $input.val();
                if(isURL(item.text)) {
                    if(item) item.url = item.text;
                } else {
                    if(item) item.url = null;
                }
                
                if(item) item.url_title = $url_title.val();
                if(item) item.url_description = $url_description.val();
                if(item) item.url_image = $url_image.val();

    _this.addDOM();
    _this.element.triggerHandler('change');
    //_this.hide();
   });
   /*$input.on('change', function() {

    var x = $e.attr('data-x'),
     y = $e.attr('data-y'),
     item = $.grep(_this.data, function(v) {
      return v.x == x && v.y == y;
     }).pop();
    
    if(item) item.text = $input.val();
              

    _this.addDOM();
    _this.element.triggerHandler('change');
   });
   */
   $e.empty().append($input, $button_ok, $button_delete, $url_preview, $url_title, $url_description, $url_image);
            
            
  });
  
  _this.updateDOM();
        
 };
 
 /****************************************************************
  * DATA MANAGEMENT
  ****************************************************************/
 
 Taggd.prototype.addData = function(data) {
  if($.isArray(data)) {
   this.data = $.merge(this.data, data);
  } else {
   this.data.push(data);
  }
  
  if(this.initialized) {
   this.addDOM();
   this.element.triggerHandler('change');
  }
 };
 
 Taggd.prototype.setData = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  
  if(this.initialized) {
   this.addDOM();
  }
 };
 
 Taggd.prototype.clear = function() {
  if(!this.initialized) return;
  this.wrapper.find('.taggd-item, .taggd-item-hover').remove();
 };
 
 
 /****************************************************************
  * EVENTS
  ****************************************************************/
 
 Taggd.prototype.on = function(event, handler) {
  if(
   typeof event !== 'string' ||
   typeof handler !== 'function'
  ) return;
  
  this.element.on(event, handler);
 };
 
 
 /****************************************************************
  * TAGS MANAGEMENT
  ****************************************************************/
 
 Taggd.prototype.iterateTags = function(a, yep) {
  var func;
  
  if($.isNumeric(a)) {
   func = function(i, e) { return a === i; };
  } else if(typeof a === 'string') {
   func = function(i, e) { return $(e).is(a); }
  } else if($.isArray(a)) {
   func = function(i, e) {
    var $e = $(e);
    var result = false;
    
    $.each(a, function(ai, ae) {
     if(
      i === ai ||
      e === ae ||
      $e.is(ae)
     ) {
      result = true;
      return false;
     }
    });
    
    return result;
   }
  } else if(typeof a === 'object') {
   func = function(i, e) {
    var $e = $(e);
    return $e.is(a);
   };
  } else if($.isFunction(a)) {
   func = a;
  } else if(!a) {
   func = function() { return true; }
  } else return this;
  
  this.wrapper.find('.taggd-item').each(function(i, e) {
   if(typeof yep === 'function' && func.call(this, i, e)) {
    yep.call(this, i, e);
   }
  });
  
  return this;
 };
 
 Taggd.prototype.show = function(a) {
  return this.iterateTags(a, methods.show);
 };
 
 Taggd.prototype.hide = function(a) {
  return this.iterateTags(a, methods.hide);
 };
 
 Taggd.prototype.toggle = function(a) {
  return this.iterateTags(a, methods.toggle);
 };
 
 /****************************************************************
  * CLEANING UP
  ****************************************************************/
 
 Taggd.prototype.dispose = function() {
  this.clear();
  this.element.unwrap(this.wrapper);
 };
 
 
 /****************************************************************
  * SEMI-PRIVATE
  ****************************************************************/
 
 Taggd.prototype.addDOM = function() {
  var _this = this;
  
  this.clear();
  this.element.css({ height: 'auto', width: 'auto' });
  
  var height = this.element.height();
  var width = this.element.width();
  
  $.each(this.data, function(i, v) {
   var $item = $('<span />');
   var $hover;
   
   if(
    v.x > 1 && v.x % 1 === 0 &&
    v.y > 1 && v.y % 1 === 0
   ) {
    v.x = v.x / width;
    v.y = v.y / height;
   }
   
   if(typeof v.attributes === 'object') {
    $item.attr(v.attributes);
   }
   
   $item.attr({
    'data-x': v.x,
    'data-y': v.y
   });
   
   $item.css('position', 'absolute');
   $item.addClass('taggd-item');
   
   _this.wrapper.append($item);
   
   if(typeof v.text === 'string' && (v.text.length > 0 || _this.options.edit)) {
    $hover = $('<span class="taggd-item-hover" style="position: absolute;" />').html(v.text);
    
    $hover.attr({
     'data-x': v.x,
     'data-y': v.y
    });
    
    _this.wrapper.append($hover);
   }
   
   if(typeof _this.options.handlers === 'object') {
    $.each(_this.options.handlers, function(event, func) {
     var handler;
     
     if(typeof func === 'string' && methods[func]) {
      handler = methods[func];
     } else if(typeof func === 'function') {
      handler = func;
     }
     
     $item.on(event, function(e) {
      if(!handler) return;
      handler.call($item, e, _this.data[i]);
     });
    });
   }
  });
  
  this.element.removeAttr('style');
  
  if(this.options.edit) {
   this.alterDOM();
            
  }
  
  this.updateDOM();
 };
 
 Taggd.prototype.updateDOM = function() {
  var _this = this;
  
  this.wrapper.removeAttr('style').css({
   height: this.element.height(),
   width: this.element.width()
  });
  
  this.wrapper.find('span').each(function(i, e) {
   var $el = $(e);
   
   var left = $el.attr('data-x') * _this.element.width();
   var top = $el.attr('data-y') * _this.element.height();
   
   if($el.hasClass('taggd-item')) {
    $el.css({
     left: left - $el.outerWidth(true) / 2,
     top: top - $el.outerHeight(true) / 2
    });
   } else if($el.hasClass('taggd-item-hover')) {
    if(_this.options.align.x === 'center') {
     left -= $el.outerWidth(true) / 2;
    } else if(_this.options.align.x === 'right') {
     left -= $el.outerWidth(true);
    }
    
    if(_this.options.align.y === 'center') {
     top -= $el.outerHeight(true) / 2;
    } else if(_this.options.align.y === 'bottom') {
     top -= $el.outerHeight(true);
    }
    
    $el.attr('data-align', $el.outerWidth(true));
    
    $el.css({
     left: left + _this.options.offset.left,
     top: top + _this.options.offset.top
    });
   }
  });
 };
 
 
 /****************************************************************
  * JQUERY LINK
  ****************************************************************/
 
 $.fn.taggd = function(options, data) {
  return new Taggd(this, options, data);
 };
})(jQuery);
```

I thought this would do what i want, since it works with the standard text input box, using .val($e.text()),  works fine but as soon as i do the same to the url_title box, for example .val($e.url_title()), i get the error below.

```js
    $input = $('<input id="url" type="text" size="16" />')
     .val($e.text()),
                $url_title = $('<input type="text" id="url_title" class="url_title" />'),
    $button_ok = $('<button />')
     .html(_this.options.strings.save),
                
                $url_description = $('<input type="text" class="url_description" id="url_description" />'),
                $url_image = $('<input type="text" class="url_img" id="url_img" />'),
                $url_preview = $('<div id="content"></div>'),
    $button_delete = $('<button />')
     .html(_this.options.strings.delete);
```

But if for example i change the $url_title to

```js
$url_title = $('<input type="text" id="url_title" class="url_title" />').val($e.url_title()),
```

I get a error back in the console:
**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

This is the init code on the main page:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var options = {
  edit: true,
  
  align: {
   y: 'top'
  },

  offset: {
   top: 15
  },

  handlers: {
      //mouseenter: 'show',
   click: 'toggle'
  }
 };
 
 /*var data = [
  { x: 0.22870478413068845, y: 0.41821946169772256, text: 'Eye'             },
  { x: 0.51, y: 0.5, text: 'Bird'             },
  { x: 0.40, y: 0.3, text: 'Water, obviously' }
 ];*/
 var data = [];
 
 var taggd = $('.taggd').taggd( options, data );
 
 taggd.on('change', function() {
  console.log(taggd.data);
 });
 });
```

In the console log it logs the values fine:

```
[Object]0: Objecttext: "http://stackoverflow.com"url: "http://stackoverflow.com"url_description: "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers"url_image: "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=ea71a5211a91&a"url_title: "Stack Overflow"x: 0.41141586360266863y: 0.19444444444444445
```

I hope someone can shine a light on it and point me in the right direction of what i'm doing wrong.

To simplify it, i want to be able to have a title input and a description input for my tags, how would i achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `$e.url_title()` is causing the error, as far as I know, `url_title()` isn't a method you can call on jQuery instances.

Presumably you meant to access a variable instead.

---

I couldn’t find an issue in your scripts, other than the undefined function call, so I basically rewrote the whole thing myself, which seems to work: http://jsbin.com/nexujuhefo/2/edit?js,console,output

I think the problem is Taggd weird logic ;)

---

Fields now remember data: http://jsbin.com/hosipiyuqa/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Yes, i know that is causing the error. I want to do the same like you can do with the $e.text()  to keep the input value on the input field, but then for the other input fields.

So when i click on a tag which i have created i want the input fields to hold the values that got populated by the ajax call.

So basicly, what should i do to get the url_title in the tag box? I want if someone clicks on the tag again that the input fields are still holding the value's. I already got the url_title, url_description, url_image in the data array and is outputting fine in the console.

Comment: To simplify what i want to achieve is, standard the plugin comes with 1 text input, but i want to use more, so i can have a title and a description for my tag. How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, i have run the code, but basicly i already had that part working of passing the right values to the data array. I just need the input fields on each tag to STAY populated with the values. Unless you delete the tag or edit the fields.

Comment: I had that working as well, but as soon as you add another tag and the input fields get populated with the fake ajax call the previous tag loses its input values... i guess this is because of the addDOM() or updateDOM() function? 

Just try add 2 or 3 tags in your example and see it for yourself...